# Gravity dramatically changing when adding player controls

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

so if when I add my rigidbody2D the gravity works as it normally would. my player sprite falls down and it's velocity downwards increases. Once I add some very simple player controls it seems to almost be throttled? bumping up the gravity to something like 50 still doesn't feel the same as gravity=1 (default settings) without my player control script. here's my code.

```
public class playerControlls : MonoBehaviour {

public float maxSpeed;

void Update(){
    float moveH = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveH, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    rigidbody2D.velocity = movement * maxSpeed;
}
}
```

Comment: this thing once happened with me problem was mesh collider you can try making its size bigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting you sprites velocity to be limited by maxSpeed, this includes its falling speed.

```
rigidbody2D.velocity = movement * maxSpeed;
```

Means the sprite will never achieve downwards speeds that exceed maxSpeed.
When setting the movement vector, include `rigidbody.velocity.y`.

```
void Update() {
    float moveH = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveH, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    movement *= maxSpeed;
    movement.y = rigidbody2D.velocity.y; //movement vector now maintains current falling speed
    rigidbody2D.velocity = movement;
}
```

Comment: the "movement * maxSpeed" line has an error. movement is highlighted and I get this error -  The type or namespace name `movement' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Sorry, that was a coding error. It should be `movement *= maxSpeed` not `movement * maxSpeed` I've updated the answer with the code fix as well.